# Deleting text from a file

Tags: sed

I am having a problem deleting a range of text from a file. See the file example below:

```
<transaction>
some text
some text
some text
</transaction>
<transaction>
some text
some text
some text
</transaction>
<transaction>
some text
some text
some text
</transaction>
```

I only want to delete beginning with the first `<transaction>` and ending with
the first : `</transaction>`. The delete should include `<transaction>` and `</transaction>`.

I think this can be accomplished using `sed`. But I have been unable to make it work.

Comment: don't just say that you can't get it to work, include your code (**in your Q above**), then people can help you fix your understanding of how sed works. We want to teach you how to fish, not to catch a fish for you ;-) . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
awk '/transaction/ {b++} b>2'
```

Output:

```
<transaction>
some text
some text
some text
</transaction>
<transaction>
some text
some text
some text
</transaction>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input is like the one in the example, you can do that more easily with awk:

```
awk '{ if (p) print $0 }; $0=="</transaction>" { p = 1 }' input.txt
```

**Edit:**

if you need to skip the lines from, e.g., the 4th `<transaction>` to the next one:

```
awk 'BEGIN { p = 0 }; $0=="<transaction>" { p++ }; { if (p != 4) print $0 }' input.txt
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with awk, but could you adapt the command to delete the Nth transaction entry instead?

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to delete lines with tags, use:

```
sed -e '/<\/\?transaction>/d' file.txt
```

if you want to delete tags and text between them, use:

```
sed -e '/<transaction>/,/<\/transaction>/d' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/<transaction>/{:a;n;/<\/transaction>/!ba;:b;n;p;bb};p' file
```

This puts the sed invocation into `grep` mode. Prints any lines before the first instance of `<transaction>`, does not print and lines thereafter until the tag `</transaction>` has passed and then prints the remainder of the file.

Another solution expects the text to be well formed:

```
sed '1,/<\/transaction>/{/<transaction>/h;G;//!P;d}' file
```